# Use javascript to auto slide carousel instead of built in navigation

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, slider, carousel

I love this image and text carousel created by the always inspiring Codrops at www.tympanus.net.
The specific example can be found here: [Code Example](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/02/27/text-trail-effect/)

My question is how can I adapt the javascript to make it auto play, so the navigation is still clickable but it moves on after a couple of seconds?
I've included the file content:

```
{
class TextFX {
    constructor(el) {
        this.DOM = {el: el};
        // The texts (repeated)
        this.DOM.texts = [...this.DOM.el.querySelectorAll('.content__text')];
        this.DOM.textsTotal = this.DOM.texts.length;
        // The index of the main text element
        this.middleIdx = Math.floor(this.DOM.textsTotal/2);
        // Time between each showing/hiding of each text instance
        this.loopInterval = {show: 80, hide: 80};
        // optional: Extra time to the whole show/hide animation. 
        this.loopEndIddleTime = this.loopInterval.show;
    }
    show({dir = 'both', halfwayCallback = null} = {}) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const loopHide = (pos) => {
                if ( this.middleIdx-pos === this.middleIdx ) {
                    setTimeout(resolve, this.loopEndIddleTime);
                    return;
                }
                this.hideText(pos, dir);
                setTimeout(() => loopHide(pos-1), this.loopInterval.hide);
            };
            const loopShow = (pos) => {
                if ( this.middleIdx-pos > this.middleIdx ) {
                    if ( halfwayCallback && typeof halfwayCallback === 'function') {
                        halfwayCallback();
                    }
                    loopHide(this.middleIdx);
                    return;
                }
                this.showText(pos, dir);
                setTimeout(() => loopShow(pos-1), this.loopInterval.show);
            };
            loopShow(this.middleIdx);
        });
    }
    hide({dir = 'both', halfwayCallback = null} = {}) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const loopHide = (pos) => {
                if ( this.middleIdx-pos < 0 ) {
                    setTimeout(resolve, this.loopEndIddleTime);
                    return;
                }
                this.hideText(pos, dir);
                setTimeout(() => loopHide(pos+1), this.loopInterval.hide);
            };
            const loopShow = (pos) => {
                if ( this.middleIdx-pos < 0 ) {
                    if ( halfwayCallback && typeof halfwayCallback === 'function') {
                        halfwayCallback();
                    }
                    loopHide(0);
                    return;
                }
                this.showText(pos, dir);
                setTimeout(() => loopShow(pos+1), this.loopInterval.show);
            };
            loopShow(1);
        });
    }
    // Hides one (dir = 'up' or dir = 'down') or more texts, specifically the equally distant texts from main text (dir = 'both')
    hideText(pos, dir) {
        this.toggleText('hide', pos, dir);
    }
    showText(pos, dir) {
        this.toggleText('show', pos, dir);
    }
    toggleText(action, pos, dir) {
        const changeStyle = {
            up: _ => {
                this.DOM.texts[this.middleIdx-pos].style.opacity = action === 'show' ? 1 : 0;
            },
            down: _ => {
                this.DOM.texts[this.middleIdx+pos].style.opacity = action === 'show' ? 1 : 0;
            }
        };
        if ( dir === 'both' ) {
            changeStyle['up']();
            changeStyle['down']();
        }
        else {
            changeStyle[dir]();
        }
    }
}

class Slide {
    constructor(el) {
        this.DOM = {el: el};
        this.DOM.img = {
            wrap: this.DOM.el.querySelector('.content__img'),
            inner: this.DOM.el.querySelector('.content__img-inner')
        };
        // The text effect class.
        this.textFX = new TextFX(this.DOM.el.querySelector('.content__text-wrap'));
    }
    // Hide the Slide's image
    hideImage(dir) {
        this.toggleImage('hide', dir);
    }
    // Show the Slide's image
    showImage(dir) {
        this.toggleImage('show', dir);
    }
    toggleImage(action, dir) {
        new TimelineMax().add('begin')
        .to(this.DOM.img.wrap, action === 'hide' ? 0.3 : 0.7, { 
            ease: action === 'hide' ? Quint.easeOut : Quint.easeOut,
            startAt: action === 'hide' ? {} : {x: dir === 'next' ? '110%' : '-110%', opacity: 1},
            x: action === 'hide' ? dir === 'next' ? '-110%' : '110%' : '0%'
        }, 'begin')
        .to(this.DOM.img.inner, action === 'hide' ? 0.3 : 0.7, { 
            ease: action === 'hide' ? Quint.easeOut : Quint.easeOut,
            startAt: action === 'hide' ? {} : {x: dir === 'next' ? '-100%' : '100%'},
            x: action === 'hide' ? dir === 'next' ? '100%' : '-100%' : '0%'
        }, 'begin');
    }
}

class Slideshow {
    constructor(el) {
        this.DOM = {el: el};
        // Navigation controls
        this.DOM.nav = {
            prev: this.DOM.el.querySelector('.content__nav-button--prev'),
            next: this.DOM.el.querySelector('.content__nav-button--next')
        };
        // All slides
        this.slides = [];
        [...this.DOM.el.querySelectorAll('.content__slide')].forEach(slide => this.slides.push(new Slide(slide)));
        // Total number of slides
        this.slidesTotal = this.slides.length;
        // Current slide position
        this.current = 0;
        // Show the first one
        this.slides[this.current].DOM.el.classList.add('content__slide--current');
        // Initialize some events
        this.initEvents();
    }
    initEvents() {
        // Clicking next and previous controls.
        this.onClickPrevFn = _ => this.navigate('prev');
        this.onClickNextFn = _ => this.navigate('next');
        this.DOM.nav.prev.addEventListener('click', this.onClickPrevFn);
        this.DOM.nav.next.addEventListener('click', this.onClickNextFn);
    }
    navigate(dir) {
        if ( this.isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }
        this.isAnimating = true;
        // Current slide
        const currentSlide = this.slides[this.current];

        // Update current
        this.current = dir === 'next' ? 
            this.current < this.slidesTotal - 1 ? this.current + 1 : 0 :
            this.current > 0 ? this.current - 1 : this.slidesTotal - 1;

        // Upcoming slide
        const upcomingSlide = this.slides[this.current];

        const onCurrentHalfwayCallback = () => {
            // Hide the current slide's image
            currentSlide.hideImage(dir);
            // Set the upcoming slide's main text opacity to 1.
            upcomingSlide.textFX.DOM.texts[upcomingSlide.textFX.middleIdx].style.opacity = 0;
            // Add current class to the upcoming slide (opacity = 1)
            upcomingSlide.DOM.el.classList.add('content__slide--current');
            // Show the upcoming slide's image
            upcomingSlide.showImage(dir);
        };
        const onCurrentEndCallback = () => {
            // Remove the current class from the current slide.
            currentSlide.DOM.el.classList.remove('content__slide--current');
            upcomingSlide.textFX.show().then(() => this.isAnimating = false);
        };
        // Hide the current slide's text, 
        // and call onCurrentHalfwayCallback at half of the animation
        // In the end call onCurrentEndCallback
        currentSlide.textFX.hide({halfwayCallback:     onCurrentHalfwayCallback}).then(onCurrentEndCallback);
    }
}

// Initialize the slideshow
new Slideshow(document.querySelector('.content_wrap'));

// Preload all the images in the page
imagesLoaded(document.querySelectorAll('.content__img-inner'), {background: true}, () => document.body.classList.remove('loading'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reading the code closely couldn't you just find the "next" button and click it on some interval?

Something like

```
setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector('.content__nav-button--next').click()
    },3000);
```

It looks like the code already handles the case where it gets triggered while animating - and does nothing.

```
navigate(dir) {
    if ( this.isAnimating ) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. So simple, I need to learn so much more JS. :D